# Tkinter, I cannot get my slider to show all buttons

Tags: python, button, canvas, tkinter, scrollbar

Here is a sample of what I am doing. I put 500 buttons on a sliding canvas, and I can only scroll to button 109. What am I doing wrong? I've tried adjusting the width on the widgets, as well as the scrollregion. I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple.

```
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import os, signal

window1 = Tkinter.Tk()
window1.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window1.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: e.widget.quit())

window2 = Tkinter.Label(window1)
window2.configure(bg = "blue")
window2.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame=Frame(window2, height=160)
frame.pack(anchor=Tkinter.SW,side=Tkinter.BOTTOM)

canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='black', width=5500, height=160, scrollregion=(0,0,5500,0))

hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL, bg='black', troughcolor='black')
hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)

canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, xscrollincrement=4.5)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)
frm = Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=frm, anchor='nw')

def quit():
    window1.quit()

count = 0
while (count < 500):
    X = Tkinter.Button(frm, text=str(count), height=6, width=5, padx=0, pady=0, highlightcolor="blue", highlightthickness=3, command=quit)
    X.pack(side = "left")
    count = count + 1

window1.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `scrollregion` on the `Canvas` instance isn't wide enough. You can calculate how wide it needs to be based on the requested width of all the buttons, and then set the `scrollregion` after you've made all the buttons, like this:

```
import Tkinter
import os, signal

window1 = Tkinter.Tk()
window1.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
window1.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: e.widget.quit())

window2 = Tkinter.Label(window1)
window2.configure(bg = "blue")
window2.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

frame = Tkinter.Frame(window2, height=160)
frame.pack(anchor=Tkinter.SW,side=Tkinter.BOTTOM)

canvas=Tkinter.Canvas(frame,bg='black', width=5500, height=160)

hbar=Tkinter.Scrollbar(frame,orient=Tkinter.HORIZONTAL, bg='black', troughcolor='black')
hbar.pack(side=Tkinter.BOTTOM,fill=Tkinter.X)
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)

canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, xscrollincrement=4.5)
canvas.pack(side=Tkinter.LEFT, expand=True, fill=Tkinter.BOTH)
frm = Tkinter.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=frm, anchor='nw')

def quit():
    window1.quit()

count = 0
width = 0
while (count < 500):
    X = Tkinter.Button(frm, text=str(count), height=6, width=5, padx=0, pady=0, highlightcolor="blue", highlightthickness=3, command=quit)
    X.pack(side = "left")
    width += X.winfo_reqwidth()
    count = count + 1

canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, width, 0))
window1.mainloop()
```

As a side note, your first two import statements are redundant. In this example, I dropped the second one to avoid polluting the global namespace.